# Access shared folder over vpn

Tags: macos, openvpn, synology

I have a Synology NAS that I would like to access while I'm away. I have set up OpenVPN on my NAS and can successfully connect to it. When I am connected though the shared folder does not show up in Finder like it normally does when I'm at home. I can Go to my folder but only by using it's IP address and not it's name. What I would like it to do is to show my NAS in the Shared column in finder automatically like what it does now.

I thought at first that it was because of the different subnets. By default OpenVPN was assigning IPs to 10.8.0.x and my home subnet is 192.168.1.x. So I changed OpenVPN to assign IP addresses to 192.168.2.x and changed the subnet mask on my router to 255.255.0.0. This did not solve the problem however.

Why is OS X not showing my shared folder when I'm connected over VPN and how do I fix it?

Comment: Is your DNS working over the VPN? What version of DiskStation Manager are you running?

Comment: I'll have to check the nameserver when I'm connected via VPN. I'm not running a DNS on my NAS though. I'm just using my router and it's default DNS (ISPs DNS). I'm running DSM 5.2 beta.

Comment: Where is OpenVPN running; on your router, the NAS, or your computer? Might need to explain your network layout a bit more.

Comment: @thndrwrks did you ever find a solution to this issue. I am having the same problem now.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are testing from outside your home network, it sounds like a DNS resolution problem. See [this page](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/13907/7126) for some background.

Comment: Ok you've found the source of the problem. My DNS is not being changed when I connect to the VPN. This is strange to me because I'm rerouting all my traffic through the VPN.